# Bootstrap one column width wider but only on large screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am following the bootstrap documentation for making one column wider than the other 2. 
JSFiddle at the bottom of question.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#setting-one-column-width

I want to create this length with 3 cols **only for large devies**:
[image]

When I tried:

```
<div class="row no-lf-margin">
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-12 col-sm-12 bg-warning">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-7 col-lg-7 col-md-12 col-sm-12 bg-danger">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12 bg-secondary">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

I got this:
[image]

But the first col (col 1, orange) is taking a bit more space than it needs to and col 3 (grey) is also taking too much space. When I set col-xl-2 to col1, it takes too little space and when I set col-xl-1 to col3, it takes too little space too. It's like I need col-xl-2.5 for col1, and col-xl-1.5 for col3.

Note: The other screens (md, small etc.) work fine, they stack on top of each other because of col-md-12 and col-sm-12.

---

So I created this according to the documentation:

```
<div class="row no-lf-margin">
      <div class="col bg-warning">
         1
      </div>
      <div class="col-7 bg-danger">
        2
      </div>
      <div class="col bg-secondary">
        3
      </div>
</div>
```

The result is good for the col1 (orange), the width is good. But col3 (grey) is still too big. Also now on all screens the cols are next to each other, not below on another because there is not col-md-12 and col-sm-12:
[image]

I tried creating a hybrid of these two:

```
  <div class="row no-lf-margin">
    <div class="col col-md-12 col-sm-12 bg-warning">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-7 col-md-12 col-sm-12 bg-danger">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col col-md-12 col-sm-12 bg-secondary">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

But I just got col-12 everywhere, where they stack on top of each other.

---

**JSFiddle with both versions and goal: https://jsfiddle.net/gcdn3str/**

Comment: if you divide 1920/12 it makes 160 , how is it supposed to rebuild columns of  204px, 540px and 1177px from bits of 160px ? You'll need here to make your own custom class

Comment: The width of the col doesn't have to be exact like in the image. I just want to make col1 and col3 shorter in width, not exactly in pixels. @G-Cyr

Comment: use `col-md` same as for `lg`

Comment: Why not set it up as `col-3 col-7 col-2` for each column respectively?

Answer (score 1):

In a `.row`, `.col`'s in bootstrap must always add up to 12. So if you have 2 `col-6`, they will be same size taking up 50%. So in your case if you had 3 `col-4` they would all take up 1/3 of the page. If you want to have some bigger than others, you can do: `col-4` `col-5` `col-3` or some other combination of that, which adds to 12.

For example:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        3
    </div>
</div>
```

Within a column, you can put another row with columns and in that way you can loophole the sizing of them. For example if the first column is fine, but the other 2 need to be adjusted you can do something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7">
            2
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5">
            3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Have a play with that and see if you can loophole a situation that works for you!

Comment: I know this. The thing I want to change is the specific width to a col, I want one to be wider. So in your example, imagine I want to make the width of `col-md-4` a bit smaller and `col-md-5` a bit wider. Changing the code to `col-md-3` is too much shorter.

Comment: @IkePr Made an edit that fixes your problem, however you need to play around with it a bit

Comment: Also to ensure that there is no horizontal scrolling on your page all rows and columns on your page should be within a `<div class="container-fluid"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```css
.item
    {
        padding: 2rem;
    }
    
    .orange
    {
        background-color: orange;
    }

    .red
    {
        background-color: red;
    }

    .gray
    {
        background-color: gray;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="item col-12 col-lg-3 orange"></div>
            <div class="item col-12 col-lg-8 red"></div>
            <div class="item col-12 col-lg-1 gray"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```